# SQL Server database tuning for a self-join without denormalization

Tags: sql-server, performance, self-join, database-tuning

I have a TPC-H database and workload and I'm dealing with the following query (query 21 in TPC-H):

```
SELECT  TOP 100
    S_NAME, COUNT(*) AS NUMWAIT
FROM    SUPPLIER S
JOIN NATION N ON S.S_NATIONKEY = N.N_NATIONKEY  AND N.N_NAME        = 'JORDAN'
JOIN LINEITEM L1 ON S.S_SUPPKEY = L1.L_SUPPKEY AND L1.L_RECEIPTDATE > L1.L_COMMITDATE
JOIN ORDERS O ON O.O_ORDERKEY = L1.L_ORDERKEY AND O.O_ORDERSTATUS       = 'F'
WHERE EXISTS    (
            SELECT  *
            FROM    LINEITEM L2
            WHERE   L2.L_ORDERKEY   = L1.L_ORDERKEY AND
                L2.L_SUPPKEY    <> L1.L_SUPPKEY 
        )
GROUP   BY  S_NAME
ORDER   BY  NUMWAIT DESC, S_NAME
```

The query is slightly modified to the original just to make the problem more clear. The idea of the query is to find suppliers names who kept multi-supplier orders waiting. Query identifies suppliers, for a given nation. The major problem in this query is to identify multi-supplier orders, which is basically that exists condition.

If I create the following indexes:

```
CREATE VIEW LINEITEM_VIOLATE1 WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT L_ORDERKEY, L_LINENUMBER, L_SUPPKEY
FROM dbo.LINEITEM
WHERE L_RECEIPTDATE > L_COMMITDATE
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX noncluster_idx_lineitem_orderkey1
ON LINEITEM_VIOLATE1(L_ORDERKEY, L_LINENUMBER, L_SUPPKEY)
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nonclustered_idx_lineitem_suppkey1
ON [dbo].[LINEITEM_VIOLATE1] ([L_SUPPKEY])
INCLUDE ([L_ORDERKEY])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX change2
ON [dbo].[ORDERS] ([O_ORDERSTATUS])
INCLUDE ([O_ORDERKEY])
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX change3
ON [dbo].[LINEITEM] ([L_ORDERKEY])
INCLUDE ([L_SUPPKEY])
GO
```

I get quite good query plan with the following results:

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ORDERS'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1719, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'LINEITEM'. Scan count 137252, logical reads 437982, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'LINEITEM_VIOLATE1'. Scan count 362, logical reads 1484, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'SUPPLIER'. Scan count 1, logical reads 205, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'NATION'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(1 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 938 ms,  elapsed time = 1134 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

The task, searching for orders that has more than one unique supplier, takes more than a half of the time. It can be observed in a number of logical reads of LINEITEM, in a query plan (self-join is estimated having a 79% cost) and I also tested removing the exists clause which lead to a half CPU time. It is not possible to create an indexed view for this subquery since it contains a self-join. I would like to achieve maximal performance without denormalization. Do you have any idea how to further push the performance of this query? Thanks for any insights.

---

I just add the textual representation of the query plan:

```
    100 1   SELECT TOP 100   S_NAME,   COUNT(*) AS NUMWAIT  FROM SUPPLIER S  JOIN NATION N ON S.S_NATIONKEY = N.N_NATIONKEY AND N.N_NAME  = 'JORDAN'  JOIN LINEITEM L1 ON S.S_SUPPKEY = L1.L_SUPPKEY AND L1.L_RECEIPTDATE > L1.L_COMMITDATE  JOIN ORDERS O ON O.O_ORDERKEY = L1.L_ORDERKEY AND O.O_ORDERSTATUS  = 'F'  WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *     FROM LINEITEM L2     WHERE L2.L_ORDERKEY = L1.L_ORDERKEY AND      L2.L_SUPPKEY <> L1.L_SUPPKEY     )  GROUP BY S_NAME  ORDER BY NUMWAIT DESC,    S_NAME    ----- 1   1   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    100 NULL    NULL    NULL    49,24822    NULL    NULL    SELECT  0   NULL
    100 1     |--Sort(TOP 100, ORDER BY:([Expr1016] DESC, [S].[S_NAME] ASC))    1   2   1   Sort    TopN Sort   TOP 100, ORDER BY:([Expr1016] DESC, [S].[S_NAME] ASC)   NULL    100 0,01126126  0,5933996   36  49,24822    [S].[S_NAME], [Expr1016]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    0   0          |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1016]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1024],0)))    1   3   2   Compute Scalar  Compute Scalar  DEFINE:([Expr1016]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1024],0))  [Expr1016]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1024],0)   9931,421    0   0,6267112   36  48,64356    [S].[S_NAME], [Expr1016]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    362 1               |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([S].[S_NAME]), RESIDUAL:([SUPPLIER].[S_NAME] as [S].[S_NAME] = [SUPPLIER].[S_NAME] as [S].[S_NAME]) DEFINE:([Expr1024]=COUNT(*)))    1   4   3   Hash Match  Aggregate   HASH:([S].[S_NAME]), RESIDUAL:([SUPPLIER].[S_NAME] as [S].[S_NAME] = [SUPPLIER].[S_NAME] as [S].[S_NAME])   [Expr1024]=COUNT(*) 9931,421    0   0,6267112   36  48,64356    [S].[S_NAME], [Expr1024]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    63631   1                    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([L1].[L_ORDERKEY])=([O].[O_ORDERKEY])) 1   5   4   Hash Match  Inner Join  HASH:([L1].[L_ORDERKEY])=([O].[O_ORDERKEY]) NULL    48872,45    0   4,75613 32  48,01685    [S].[S_NAME]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    132283  1                         |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([L1].[L_ORDERKEY], [L1].[L_SUPPKEY], [Expr1023]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH) 1   6   5   Nested Loops    Left Semi Join  OUTER REFERENCES:([L1].[L_ORDERKEY], [L1].[L_SUPPKEY], [Expr1023]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH    NULL    64854   0   0,3012108   36  41,18718    [S].[S_NAME], [L1].[L_ORDERKEY] NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    137252  1                         |    |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([S].[S_SUPPKEY], [Expr1022]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)    1   10  6   Nested Loops    Inner Join  OUTER REFERENCES:([S].[S_SUPPKEY], [Expr1022]) OPTIMIZED WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH    NULL    72060   0   0,3012108   40  1,893772    [S].[S_NAME], [LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_ORDERKEY], [LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_SUPPKEY] NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    362 1                         |    |    |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([N].[N_NATIONKEY])=([S].[S_NATIONKEY])) 1   13  10  Hash Match  Inner Join  HASH:([N].[N_NATIONKEY])=([S].[S_NATIONKEY])    NULL    400 0   0,06381615  36  0,2325338   [S].[S_SUPPKEY], [S].[S_NAME]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    1   1                         |    |    |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([NATION] AS [N]), WHERE:([NATION].[N_NAME] as [N].[N_NAME]='JORDAN'))    1   14  13  Table Scan  Table Scan  OBJECT:([NATION] AS [N]), WHERE:([NATION].[N_NAME] as [N].[N_NAME]='JORDAN')    [N].[N_NATIONKEY]   1   0,003125    0,0001845   36  0,0033095   [N].[N_NATIONKEY]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    10000   1                         |    |    |    |--Table Scan(OBJECT:([SUPPLIER] AS [S]))  1   15  13  Table Scan  Table Scan  OBJECT:([SUPPLIER] AS [S])  [S].[S_SUPPKEY], [S].[S_NAME], [S].[S_NATIONKEY]    10000   0,1542361   0,011157    40  0,1653931   [S].[S_SUPPKEY], [S].[S_NAME], [S].[S_NATIONKEY]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
    137252  362                       |    |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[nonclustered_idx_lineitem_suppkey1]), SEEK:([LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_SUPPKEY]=[SUPPLIER].[S_SUPPKEY] as [S].[S_SUPPKEY]) ORDERED FORWARD)  1   17  10  Index Seek  Index Seek  OBJECT:([LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[nonclustered_idx_lineitem_suppkey1]), SEEK:([LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_SUPPKEY]=[SUPPLIER].[S_SUPPKEY] as [S].[S_SUPPKEY]) ORDERED FORWARD [LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_ORDERKEY], [LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_SUPPKEY]   180,15  0,003125    0,000355165 15  1,360028    [LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_ORDERKEY], [LINEITEM_VIOLATE1].[L_SUPPKEY]   NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   400
    132283  137252                        |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([LINEITEM].[change3] AS [L2]), SEEK:([L2].[L_ORDERKEY]=[LINEITEM].[L_ORDERKEY] as [L1].[L_ORDERKEY]),  WHERE:([LINEITEM].[L_SUPPKEY] as [L2].[L_SUPPKEY]<>[LINEITEM].[L_SUPPKEY] as [L1].[L_SUPPKEY]) ORDERED FORWARD) 1   23  6   Index Seek  Index Seek  OBJECT:([LINEITEM].[change3] AS [L2]), SEEK:([L2].[L_ORDERKEY]=[LINEITEM].[L_ORDERKEY] as [L1].[L_ORDERKEY]),  WHERE:([LINEITEM].[L_SUPPKEY] as [L2].[L_SUPPKEY]<>[LINEITEM].[L_SUPPKEY] as [L1].[L_SUPPKEY]) ORDERED FORWARD   NULL    1   0,003125    0,0001614009    11  38,95377    NULL    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   72060
    729413  1                         |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([ORDERS].[change2] AS [O]), SEEK:([O].[O_ORDERSTATUS]='F') ORDERED FORWARD) 1   24  5   Index Seek  Index Seek  OBJECT:([ORDERS].[change2] AS [O]), SEEK:([O].[O_ORDERSTATUS]='F') ORDERED FORWARD  [O].[O_ORDERKEY]    729413  1,271023    0,8025113   11  2,073534    [O].[O_ORDERKEY]    NULL    PLAN_ROW    0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying to base this off of a derived table with a having clause, supported by an index, instead of a self referencing exists?

```
FROM
(
SELECT
L_ORDERKEY
FROM
LINEITEM
GROUP BY
L_ORDERKEY
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT L_SUPPKEY) > 1
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_LINEITEM_Mult_SUPPKEY
ON [dbo].[LINEITEM] ([L_ORDERKEY],[L_SUPPKEY])
```

Your current query performance, assuming a bunch of unstated indexes, would either be based on the selectivity of orders in status F, or on the selectivity of the suppliers in the matching nation key. But if you have very few multi supplier orders, then reversing it around like this might be helpful.

I'd have to see row counts and selectivity of all these tables, and then ensure all needed indexes are in place.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Unfortunately, LINEITEM is the largest table, therefore, such inline view is very costly by itself (no matter how selective it is). If I run this query with the index, than it has double time when compared to the original solution.